# How to check if two integers are next to each other ex. 1,4,7 cannot be together

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, shuffle

My code is a simple int array that is scrambled randomly every time the code is run. I am trying to make it so that when the numbers are scrambled (1-10) if the numbers 1, 4, or 7 are next to each other, than it will re scramble. This is my current code:

```
int[] anArray1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

shuffleArray(anArray1);

if (anArray1[0] + ) {
    for (int k = 0; k < anArray1.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(anArray1[k]);
    }
}

static void shuffleArray(int[] ar) {
    Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        int a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What is `if(anArray1[0] + )`?

Answer (score 1):

The following code calls `shuffleArray()` in a loop and then walks the array checking for adjacent values in `(1, 4, 7)`.  If found, then it will continue to shuffle.

```
int counter;
// you can add or remove numbers to check for overlapping as you need
Set<Integer> overlapNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 7));

do {
    shuffleArray(anArray1);
    counter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < anArray1.length; ++i) {
        if (overlapNumbers.contains(anArray[i])) {
            ++counter;
            // adjacent overlapping numbers
            if (counter > 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
} while (counter > 1);

System.out.println("Here is the array we retained:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(anArray1));
```

Comment: I am assuming that `shuffleArray()` does an in-place shuffle of the elements.  Your output looks correct to me.

Comment: i see. i read it wrong. i was expecting to test for `int`'s `1`,`4`, and `7` next to each other, not the different pairs from those `int`'s. good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean checkIfContains(int[] containerArray, int[] subArray) {
    int limit = containerArray.length - subArray.length;
    int[] tempArray = new int[subArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(containerArray, i, tempArray, 0, subArray.length);
        if (Arrays.equals(tempArray, subArray))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use the above method as -

```
int[] anArray1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] subArray = {1,4,7};
boolean needToReshuffle = checkIfContains(anArray1, subArray);
```

Explaination:

Iteratively creating tempArray of the size of subArray with consecutive elements of containerArray, and checking if this tempArray matches subArray.

Comment: Iteratively creating tempArray of the size of subArray with consecutive elements of containerArray, and checking if this tempArray matches subArray

Comment: I meant more *why* rather than *what* part.

Comment: Also could you post it as part of your answer rather than comment so others wouldn't need to look for it?

Comment: Sure. Will add the description in answer.
Regarding why? - a generic solution where you dont have to keep on adding more conditions to check if it's a subarray. Plus, subArray can change so it can be used more as a library than just a use and throw code.